# How i write this code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to use route within httpget request , how can I write this code in vb.net?, Here is my code:

```
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    or
    [HttpGet("create")]
```

Comment: Check the docs on [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx)

Comment: Use angle brackets < > instead of square brackets [ ].

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET uses angle brackets `<>` around its attributes.  In this case it would be:

```
<HttpGet("[action]")>
```

You can see more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx).